# How to securely submit a price via post and ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I'm making an extremely simple store in order to understand more about how payment can work (but it should really work. I will sell a few old books). The 'store' is just a simple html list of products. The cart adds and removes them via javascript. Payment is via a stripe elements integration. The simplest way to do this is just to send the total from the shopping cart to a stripe charge object. My question is: what is the best way to send the price in the cart to the stripe charge object? I'm worried specifically that people could manipulate the price before submitting, but I don't want to tie my super simple shop to a database if I can avoid it. Is my method secure enough for my purposes? What better methods exist?
More details: I have a payment form that runs a php action via a `jquery ajax` submission. The `ajax` function gets the total from the html element `$('#total')` via `jquery`. In the php document, I get the total from the `$_POST` array and charge it. 
Is this ok? Is it otherwise stupid? Or ok for a really small shop?

My demo is working, I'm just interesting in learning more about best practices. I googled 'send price from cart securely via `ajax` to `php`' but didn't see anything that answered this question.

```
<div id="total">72.00</div>
```

```
var total = parseFloat($('#total').text())*100;
        $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'charge.php',
        data: { stripeToken: token.id, stripeEmail: token.email, totalAmount: totalForm},
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
      })
```

```
$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
$total = $_POST['totalAmount'];
try{
    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
        'amount' => $total,
        'currency' => 'chf',
        'description' => 'Example charge',
        'source' => $token,
    ]);
    $charge_send = $charge->__toJSON();
    $success_msg = 'Thank you for your purchase.';
    echo json_encode(array('success' => $success, 'charge' => $charge, 'err' => $err));
}
```

It's working fine. I just want it to be as secure as it should be for my purposes.

-> Thanks for the answers! I see folks think I should have a minimal database. @HTMHell : Is this because the price otherwise cannot be securely passed?

Comment: the best way should be to sent to the server the id of the product, not the price. With the id of the product you get the price in the database.

Comment: You must store in a database the items (minimum: item ID and price). Then add to cart item IDs, and not price.

Comment: To answer you question: It could be securely passed (with https) but it has nothing to do with the problem, that the user can still change the price. As you said, it's being "passed" - meaning, the user can pass whatever he wants. That's why you pass an ID, and calculate the price yourself on the back-end.

Comment: If you only have a (very) few things you may get away without a database by defining an array of product IDs and their prices in your PHP code. You'll just have to remember to update that array any time something is sold or if you want to add a new product. Limited functionality of course but it would get the job done for what you describe.

Comment: Thanks for all of these answers! Esp @HTMHell for the info about 'passing'. Just out of curiosity, how would a user pass 'whatever' via $_POST without an input field to enter it? I guess I don't have much background on how $_POST works.

Comment: @user3036948 Everything that's being sent from the client can be manipulated, `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_COOKIE` etc. The "input" is just an interface the browser suggests. Download [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) and you will see for yourself.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks. I don't understand what this postman thing actually does, or how it relates to `$_POST`, but I'm reading about it.

Answer (score 0):

most of payment system included applications require to have user has been registered. 
It shows summary of payment complete page after user clicked on submit button and user checked everything on page. you can go payment action when user has checked. it is nice to check payment with user ID.
user account has double checked with real payments methods are good.